# Выборка строк MySQL с произвольным прореживанием. Проблемы с переменными

Tags: mysql, timestamp

В таблице присутствуют столбцы: Name_Ch char(15), Event_Time TIMESTAMP(3), Param_Value Float. Физический смысл: есть некоторое количество приборов, каждый со своим Name_Ch, каждый пишет в таблицу некоторое количество строк, в которых содержится значение параметра Param_Value и время, при котором это значение было получено, около 20 записей/сек. Разделять по таблицам не разрешается. Цель: выборка из таблицы одного Name_Ch с произвольным интервалом прореживания по времени, т.е. забираем не каждое пятое (например) значение, а заранее определяем интервал (10 сек напр, может быть до нескольких часов) и выбираем строки с интервалом 10 сек.  Написана процедура

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Read_TIME_and_RMS`(IN ParamName1 text(15), IN ParamName2 text(15), IN DSTN VARBINARY(15), IN TSbegin DATETIME(3), IN TSend DATETIME(3), IN dtsec float, IN STR_to_read INT(11))
BEGIN
 DECLARE TIMEbuf DATETIME(3);
 DECLARE startpoint DATETIME(3);
 truncate table temp_table_memory;
 SET startpoint:=TSbegin+INTERVAL dtsec SECOND;
 L: WHILE (STR_to_read>0) DO
  insert into temp_table_memory (TIME, RMS) SELECT EventTime, RMS FROM backend_test.eventdata WHERE (CHName=DSTN) and (EventTime>@startpoint) LIMIT 1;
  SET @t = FOUND_ROWS();
  IF (@t=1) THEN
  SET @STR_to_read:=@STR_to_read-1;
  SELECT MAX(TIME) into @timebuf FROM temp_table_memory;
  /* SELECT TIME into TIMEbuf FROM temp_table_memory order by `TIME` DESC limit 1;*/
  SET startpoint:=timebuf+INTERVAL dtsec SECOND;
 ELSE
 LEAVE L;
 END IF; 
END WHILE L; 
 select * from temp_table_memory;
/*truncate table temp_table_memory;*/
END
```

Алгоритм:

1. Процедура получает основные параметры- имя DSTN, временной интервал для поиска TSbegin TSend, приращение времени dtsec, количество строк Str_to_read
2. От начала интервала отсчитываем dtsec и выполняем поиск единственной строки, удовлетворяющей условию
3. Найденную пару таймстемп-значение вставляем во временную таблицу
4. Из этой временной таблицы забираем значение с максимальным таймстемпом (вариант считывать в переменные, а потом переменные вставлять во временную таблицу оказался чересчур медлительным), прибавляем к нему dtsec и выполняем следующий поиск.
5. Вываливаемся из цикла когда набрали нужное количество строк Str_to_read или если очередная выборка пуста.
6. Делаем SELECT * из временной таблицы- искомый результат.
7. Очищаем временную таблицу

Структура программы:
Открываем коннекшн к БД. Запускаем процедуру в цикле (данные постоянно добавляются в БД, вычитываем новые). Выходим из цикла и закрываем коннекшн. Тут возникают проблемы с переменными: где-то что-то не очищается, либо неправильно используется - процедура возвращает повторные значения, не соответствующее искомому интервалу.

Если в каждой итерации основного цикла открывать коннекшн, запускать процедуру, а после закрывать коннекшн, то все считывается корректно. Где искать ошибку?

Возможно, есть получше варианты реализации данной задачи. Либо меры по ускорению работы.  Основная программа написана в LabView, средство связи с БД- LV SQL Connector, работает нативно через TCP.

**UPD:** Исследовал дальше. 90% времени длится фаза Sending data. Все локально. Насчет корректности данных: текущая тестовая таблица содержит строки в порядке возрастания временной метки и никак иначе. Тут вроде все нормально. Как только такой порядок меняется, нужно в качестве TSbegin для следующей выборки брать MAX из предыдущего результата. А описанная вначале проблема так и осталась. Вроде уже и косячить нечему. Первый запрос дает правильный результат, на его основе обновляем TSbegin. В следующей итерации новый запрос возвращает 0 (текст корректен, данные есть, проверено напрямую из mysql workbench), повторяется раза три. На четвертый наконец возвращает правильный результат, обновляем TSbegin. Следующая итерация и прилетает выборка из предыдущего результата (выборка не соответствует tsbegin- tsend в процедуре). Бардак.

Comment: И кстати, зачем `SET @t = FOUND_ROWS();
  IF (@t=1) THEN` может сразу писать `IF FOUND_ROWS()=1`

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете внутри процедуры переменные с собаками. Они предназначены для совершено иного и сохраняют свое значение пока установлен коннект к базе. Так что их обязательно надо инициализировать. Обратите особое внимание - переменные `StrToRead` (параметр вашей процедуры) и `@StrToRead` - это совершенно разные переменные не имеющие никакого отношения друг к другу !

Не вижу никакой необходимости делать процедуру и временную таблицу, для решения вашей задачи. Предлагаю сделать одним запросом:

```
select EventTime,RMS from (
   select EventTime,RMS,
          @yes:=if(EventTime>@lt,1,0) YES,
          @lt:=if(@yes,EventTime+interval 10 second,@lt)
     from eventdata,(select @lt:='1970-01-01',@yes:=0) A
    where CHName='DSTN' and
          EventTime between '2016-04-14 21:00'+interval 10 second
                        and '2016-04-14 21:00'+interval 10*(20+1) second
    order by EventTime
) A
 where YES=1
 limit 20
```

Вместо даты 2016 года, 10 и 20 подставляете переменные с нужными параметрами - стартовую дату, интервал прореживания, количество записей соответственно. Верхнее ограничение по дате придется убрать, если у вас в данных бывают затянутые по времени промежутки. Я его для оптимизации по скорости включил, но в случае наличия разрывов в данных может захватить недостаточное количество строк.

**UPD**: Раз подход с процедурой на ваших данных все таки быстрее предлагаю такое усовершенствование (как раз для таких случаев полезны переменные с собаками) :

```
SET @startpoint:=TSbegin;
REPEAT
 insert into temp_table_memory (TIME, RMS)
  SELECT @startpoint:=EventTime, RMS FROM backend_test.eventdata WHERE (CHName=DSTN)
     and (EventTime>@startpoint+INTERVAL dtsec SECOND) LIMIT 1;
  SET STR_to_read:=STR_to_read-1;
UNTIL STR_to_read<=0 or FOUND_ROWS()<=0 END REPEAT;
```

Фокус в том, что переменная с `@` берет значение во время insert и не надо делать select max().

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения по переменным. К процедуре пришел для ускорения времени выполнения запроса. Типичный сценарий использования: запрашиваются данные (около 1к строк) за интервал примерно сутки (а это больше миллиона строк от одного канала) с большим прореживанием (десятки минут). В подавляющем большинстве реализаций выполнение такого запроса занимает более 10 сек, что неприемлемо. В случае с процедурой при тех же входных данных на все тратится пара секунд, что намного лучше. Ваш пример кода выполняется за 13 секунд независимо от интервала и количества записей. Огромное спасибо

Comment: Да, пока отлаживал в основной таблице создал четыре индекса, два одностолбцовых (CHname, EventTime) и два составных (EventTime-ChName и наоборот). Максимальное быстродействие с составным индексом CHname-EventTime, что ожидаемо. В порядке эксперимента пробовал для временной таблицы задать движок MEMORY, получил ухудшение быстродействия раза в два (в сравнении с myisam), что неожиданно. В любом случае спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Работает. По какой-то причине очень долго выполняется составной INSERT-SELECT, причем чем больше интервал выборки, там дольше выполняется [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9UjcjPnpFWPa1lMLXl3b2ZPOHc). Тот же INSERT-SELECT выполняется очень быстро, будучи вынесен за процедуру [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9UjcjPnpFWPTWl6QVBRZlVZeTg).

Comment: Добавил UPD в топик. Последняя модификация кода возвращает одну последнюю (очень похоже) найденную строку

Comment: @Владислав order by EventTime в запрос все таки добавьте, на знаю как оно скажется на производительности, но проверить работу с ним стоит

Comment: поправил условие выхода из цикла AND на OR

Comment: @Владислав И предлагаю чистить уже не нужные комментарии

Comment: @Владислав Так until это условие окончания ... тогда и условия на противоположные X<=0

Comment: Да, с условиями прозрачно. Время выполнения увеличилось и стало сильно зависеть от интервала выборки. Но теперь оно одинаково при выполнении в процедуре и вне ее. Странное поведение в итерациях осталось

Comment: @Владислав Тут уже ломаться нечему. По идее все зависит только от TSBegin и реконнект к базе не должен менять картину. Два выполнения подряд и одним TSBegin дают одинаковый результат ? Если так, то проверяйте как меняется begin, логирйте его куда нибудь